# S3 issue - i could upload on s3 without MFA code

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

yesterday I was struggling with a strange behaviour with S3 and users with MFA.
I have to admit that this is my first time playing with MFA authentication in AWS, and I could probably missed some proper configuration.

1.
First of all, I created a a user (let's call her "userx") with MFA enabled on virtual device with her own access key and secret key. I assigned to the user the policy "AmazonS3FullAccess".
2.
Then i created a bucker "test-bucket" with policy:

```
{
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Id": "123",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "",
            "Effect": "Deny",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": "xxxxxxx",
            "Condition": {
                "BoolIfExists": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "false"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
}
```

Now what I supposed was that only users with MFA enabled can access and do stuff on the bucket.

I run this simple script to add a file to my bucket:

```
s3_client = boto3.client('s3',aws_access_key_id="xxxxx",aws_secret_access_key="xxxxxxxxxxxxxx")
# Upload the file to S3
s3_client.upload_file('hello.txt', 'test-bucket', 'hellofake.txt')
```

I used the access key and secret key of userx that was a user with MFA enabled, and I was able to add a file to the bucket without entering the MFA code and therefore using a session token.

Is that a normal behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: `"BoolIfExists"` would deny only if the key is present, which it would not be if IAM credentials were used.  MFA requires assuming a role, which is the point at which the MFA token is validated.  I suspect the absence of they key would require a test for `"Condition": {
                "Null": {
                    "aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent": "true"
                }
            }`.  The interpretation of this somewhat nonintuitive construct is "Is `aws:MultiFactorAuthPresent` null?" "Yes (`true`) it is null."

Comment: I though the same at the beginning, and I agree with you that is nonintuitive. But my real questiona was: since a user or service has MFA enabled I don't see the point to let her doing operations (any operation) without the multi-factor-authentication, then why set MFA?

Comment: No user can do anything unless you allow them to.  At the risk of oversimplifying...  If you allow them to perform an action, via policy, but that policy doesn't require MFA, then you are allowing them to perform the action without MFA.

Comment: This probably has to do with the resource you've redacted. A resource of blah:mybucket is used for bucket-level operations (list bucket and the like). A resource of blah:mybucket/* is used for objects within the bucket. Typically you use two statements to apply similar policies on each resource string to protect the bucket and the contents similarly.